# How to display only group members in the Django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I've been developing a school application for allowing the principal and his teachers to analyze data. The principal needs to add his own people to the system. I think using Django's admin panel would be a really good choice for that.

Here, I am the superuser and the principal is the staff (who can manage things on the admin panel).

As a superuser, I can see the following output:

[image]

And here is the view for the staff:

[image]

I also have two groups (school one, school two) in the system:
[image]

The principal (staff user) John Doe belongs to the group "School Two" which  has the permissions of add/change/delete/view users.

My question is how can I list the users for a staff to see only his group of people? (no superuser and no other groups' people).

Let me share some source code I implemented to for this custom user admin view:

The forms.py file:

```
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        User = get_user_model()
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.is_staff = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

      password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

      class Meta:
         User = get_user_model()
         model = User
         fields = '__all__' #fields = ('email', 'password', 'is_active','is_staff', 'groups')

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(UserAdminChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           f = self.fields.get('user_permissions', None)
           if f is not None:
              f.queryset = f.queryset.select_related('content_type')

       def clean_password(self):
              return self.initial["password"]
```

Here is the admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User
from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm

class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      form = UserAdminChangeForm
      add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

      list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_email_verified')
      list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_active', 'groups')
      readonly_fields = ('last_login', 'date_joined',)
      fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name','last_name')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active','is_staff', 'groups')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
       add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('first_name','last_name','email', 'password1', 'password2')}
         ),
    )
       search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
       ordering = ('email',)
       filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

I am using Django 2.1. Again, how can I display users who belong to a certain group? For example, here in this case, when John Doe (staff)  logged in as admin, he should only see himself (and in future other groups members) because he only belongs to "School Two".

I would be glad if I can get some help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `get_queryset` method for the admin class like this;

```
class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        # Filter here by user group
        return qs.filter(groups__id__in=request.user.groups.all())
```

Docs for this are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

Comment: Thanks for your response @markwalker_. I tried what you posted here but now I am getting the '**int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'**' error. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Well that's a number being used to filter on a `ManyToMany` field. You'll need to query for the objects that the int relates to (that'll be the ID for the objects). Then filter on those objects.